# Is type checking a problem here? If so, why and how to fix it?

Tags: c#, oop, game-development

I am making a game where I have collectibles, and collectors who collect them. Here are the interfaces for both:

```
public interface ICollectible
{
    void OnCollect(ICollector collector);
}
public interface ICollector
{
    void Collect(ICollectible collectible);
}
```

There is an `Inventory` class for implementing `ICollector` and an `Item` class for implementing `ICollectible` (I am planning on adding more implementations for both interfaces):

```
public class Inventory:ICollector
{
    private List<Item> items;
    public void Collect(ICollectible collectible) {
        if (collectible is Item) {
            collectible.OnCollect(this);
            items.Add(collectible as Item);
        }
    }
    //...
}
public class Item : ICollectible
{
    public void OnCollect(ICollector collector)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am checking wether the `ICollectible` collected by the inventory is an `Item`, because I need to add it to the `items` collection.
Is this an issue? Typechecking usually violates [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle), but I don't think this one does, because more possible implementations of the `ICollectible` interface won't make me modify this function, because the inventory contains an `Item` list, so you will only ever be able to add `Item` objects to it.

I have thought about putting an `AddTo(Inventory inventory)` method in the `ICollectible` interface, where each subclass would decide wether they add themselves to the inventory or not, which seems like the OOP solution, but I think this one does violate OCP, because with each new implementation of `ICollector`, I would need to make a new `AddTo(OtherCollectorImplementation collector)` method in the `ICollectible` interface

So my questions are:
Is mine a bad design, or is it ok? If it is bad, please explain why.
Can you do this without type checking while also not violating any OOP principles?

Comment: This design is definitely flawed. I don't see the purpose of the interface here, if you only allow one type anyways. Or maybe you wanted to do something like `ICollector<TCollectible> where TCollectible : ICollectible` .. but hard to say what exactly you're going for, without knowing more.

Comment: There are more collector types than just the inventory, and I am planning to add more collectible types as well. Your solution seems to be pretty good tho, I will try it.